# angular post work 2nd time ord 3rd time HTTP Post

Tags: angular

I understand it is problem with async but why I have this problem if I added .subscribe and I`m waiting for message

My code

```
public redirectToDelete = (id: string) => {
      this.carService.getId(id).subscribe(result =>
         new alert(this.carService.delete(result)));
   }
```

and here is delete

```
deleteUrl = "/car/delete.php";
    delete(car: Car): any {
        this.http.post(this.deleteUrl, car)
        .subscribe(res => {
            return res;
        },
            (error => {
                return error;
            })
        )
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: @Igor I will check. Currently I`m learning angular :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to return the observable: `return this.http.post(this.deleteUrl, car)....`. Otherwise you are trying to call `subscribe` on an empty string.
- You should also specify the return type instead of `any` on your methods so you have type safety, that is one of the main benefits of using typescript.
- Your `delete` method should return the observable, not a subscription. Return the call to `post` directly.
- Use the generic overloads in `HttpClient` for type safety.

```
delete(car: Car): Observable<YourTypeHere> {
    return this.http.post<YourTypeHere>(this.deleteUrl, car);
}
```

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


public redirectToDelete = (id: string) => {
      this.carService.getId(id)
          .pipe(switchMap(r => this.carService.delete(r))) // ← switchMap is handy here, alternatively you could call the next service end point in a subscribe and then have a nested subscribe but this makes for messier code IMO
          .subscribe(result => new alert(result));
   }
```

---

As a side note if you are building a RESTful service which offers a delete then I would recommend you setup an end point that uses the http DELETE verb instead of post.

Comment: there is small problem last element I can not delete